# findFragmentByTag() gives null value in android

Tags: android, android-fragments

i am beginner in android.i found similar problem in findFragmentByTag() method.

I have 2 Fragment and one 1 Activity.i want a create a flexible Activity which is run portrait mode its run FragmentA and when it run landscape mode it run two fragment(FragmentA and FragmentB) side by side .its work when Fragments are add in xml, but i want add runtime. But I want access the FragmentB object in run time so I use findFragmentByTag() menth bt it gives null.
plz help me...

**activity_main.xml(portrait mode)**
   `

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:id="@+id/mylayout"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.example.manu.newapp.MainActivity">


</LinearLayout>
```

**activity_main.xml(landscape mode)**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

    tools:context="com.example.manu.newapp.MainActivity"
    android:id="@+id/mylayout">


</LinearLayout>
```

**FragmentA.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:padding="16dp"
android:background="#71d708"
android:orientation="vertical"

tools:context="com.example.manu.newapp.FragmentA">

<!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/hello_fragmentA" />

<LinearLayout

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="right|top">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="bye"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

**FragmentB.xml**

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:padding="16dp"
android:background="#0982eb"
android:id="@+id/fragB"
tools:context="com.example.manu.newapp.FragmentB">

<!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:text="@string/hello_blank_fragment" />        </FrameLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
    package com.example.manu.newapp;

import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Display;
import android.view.Surface;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        //methods are call here
        aDD(savedInstanceState);
        rot();

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Log.d("lenovo", "OnCreate");
    }

    public void aDD(Bundle savedInstanceState) {                         //this method add Fragments

        if (findViewById(R.id.mylayout) == null) {
            if (savedInstanceState == null) {

                FragmentA fragmentA = new FragmentA();
                FragmentB fragmentB = new FragmentB();

                FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                transaction.add(R.id.mylayout, fragmentA, "A");
                transaction.add(R.id.mylayout, fragmentB, "Btag");


                transaction.commit();
            }
        }
    }

    public void rot() {                                                   // this method check rotation and hide and unhide fragmentB
        Display display = ((WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay();
        int orientation = display.getRotation();
        FragmentB fragmentB = (FragmentB) getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("B");

        if ((orientation == Surface.ROTATION_90) || orientation == Surface.ROTATION_270) {
            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().show(fragmentB).commit();

        } else if ((orientation == Surface.ROTATION_0) || orientation == Surface.ROTATION_180) {
            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().hide(fragmentB).commit();
       }   } }
```

**FragmentA.java**

```
    package com.example.manu.newapp;

        import android.content.Context;
        import android.net.Uri;
        import android.os.Bundle;
        import android.app.Fragment;
        import android.view.LayoutInflater;
        import android.view.View;
        import android.view.ViewGroup;



public class FragmentA extends Fragment {


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_a, container, false);
    }
}
```

**FragmentB**

```
    package com.example.manu.newapp;


import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;


public class FragmentB extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_b, container, false);
    }

}
```

Comment: is this a typo? I see you add Fragment B with "Btag" but you findFragmentByTag with "B"

Comment: thanks for answer.
i change this tag name.but i have same problem (FragmentB is null)

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Manoj it's only a typo. Just change this line:

```
FragmentB fragmentB = (FragmentB) getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("B");
```

To this line:

```
FragmentB fragmentB = (FragmentB) getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("Btag");
```

Comment: thanks for answer. i change this tag name.but i have same problem (FragmentB is null)

Answer (score 0):

```
findFragmentByTag()
```

is not work onCreat() method.so I use onResume();